# How can I limit the amount of memory available to a running process?

Tags: windows-7, memory, process

In Windows 7, is it possible to somehow prevent an already-running process from consuming more than a given amount of memory? Microsoft's [Application Verifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948(v=vs.90).aspx), as far as I can tell, only allows manipulation of processes launched through it, so it's not helpful in the case of a process that's already been started.

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Just curious.

Comment: @Moab I have a service host process that periodically skyrockets up to ~1.5-2 gigabytes of memory for 30-90 minutes at a time. I'm going to reformat the machine for unrelated reasons anyway, but I'm curious as to whether or not limiting its available memory would be a viable solution.

Comment: That is a memory leak and is not normal, reinstall of OS should cure it.

Answer (score 2):

The high memory usage of `svchost.exe` is a known issue that Microsoft fixed. It comes from Windows Update which scans for new updates.

Install the following update and the issue is gone:

**Windows Update Client for Windows 7: June 2015**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3050265

> This update addresses an issue in which system performance can be
>   decreased during scans. This issue has the greatest effect on
>   computers that have a small amount of physical memory.

**Download:**
**32Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=e1861201-6bb6-468d-a18d-bb87c33a53e3

**64Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=82f50ef0-ed87-46de-9f55-090585c5ab32